# MAX Date returns 0

Tags: excel

I have 2 spreadsheets - *Data* & *Restructure History Tape*.

In column C of *Restructure History Tape*, I have dates. In column A, I have IDs. When I input an ID in cell B2 of *Data*, I would like to see the MAX date of the corresponding ID.

I've used this formula:
`=MAX(IF('Restructure History Tape'!A2:A339=Data!B2, 'Restructure History Tape'!C2:C339))` which returns 0 for any ID I put in.

The dates are formatted correctly and IDs are both formatted to general (I've also tried text)

Comment: Have you typed the formula as array formula? Instead of ENTER, you must type it pressing CTRL+ENTER+SHIFT. Also, if you have Excel365, check function [MAXIFS function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/maxifs-function-dfd611e6-da2c-488a-919b-9b6376b28883). Also, make sure those dates are being recognized properly.

Comment: Perhaps the dates are actually text (do they actually change format if you change the cell format to General?), or the IDs are text in one sheet and numeric in the other.

Comment: Your If function  only has two parameters.  Is that a misprint  and you meant to use maxif?

Comment: Used array formula and worked correctly.

Comment: The formula used is correct to fetch the desired output. Issue may be with the cell format!